# LEGO BOOST failing firmware update

Tags: software, boost

We have a LEGO BOOST kit. When going through the initial setup, we get as far as connecting the move hub to the tablet and then it asks if we want to do a firmware update. There is no option other than 'OK'. The light on the hub flashes pink briefly and then goes out. The progress bar doesn't progress, and then it reverts back to the screen asking us to turn the hub back on.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this by installing the powered up app and performing the update through this.

Comment: This is quite annoying.. but through powered up app (as proposed by xanld), the firmare was updated easily.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, so recommended holding a green button until the LED will start flashing purple.

Comment: Powered Up worked for me. The listing of Lego products doesn't contain Lego Boost, perhaps because it's a discontinued product? I chose Lego Ideas (the piano) and I was able to update the firmware.